# What is the differences between Node *node[100] and Node node[100]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was trying to create a adjancecy list then i wrote this code:

```
struct No{
    int atual;
    No *prox;
    No(int n){
        atual = n;
    }       
};

No adj[101];
```

But when I tried to compile it, an compile error occurred.

Then I changed this line `No adj[101];` to this: `No *adj[101];` and the code compiled successfully.

What is the difference between `Node *no[10]` and `Node no[10]`?

Comment: One of those calls the non-existent default constructor.

Comment: First (Node *no[10]) is declaration of array of pointers to Node, second (Node no[10]) is declaration of array of Node structures.

Comment: [What is clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) ?

Comment: Show the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`No a[100]` defines an array of `100` objects while `No* a[100]` defines an array of `100` pointers. When defining an array of objects, each object can be defined using the default constructor or another constructor that has default arguments to act like a default constructor. Since you have not defined an appropriate constructor, the compiler is not able to find a way to initialize the objects in the array. There is no such problem with the array of pointers.

You can fix it by providing a default constructor or changing the current constructor with a default value of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

`No adj[101]` is an array of structures `No`.
`No *adj[101]` is an array of pointers to structs `No`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that one declares an array of structures, and the other declares an array of pointers to structures -- but that's not your problem.

Here's a simpler example that illustrates the problem you're having:

```
struct foo {
    foo(int n) {
        // nothing
    }       
};

foo obj;
```

and here are the error messages I get from g++:

```
c.cpp:7:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo()’
c.cpp:7:5: note: candidates are:
c.cpp:2:5: note: foo::foo(int)
c.cpp:2:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
c.cpp:1:8: note: foo::foo(const foo&)
c.cpp:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

The problem is that you've provided a constructor that takes one argument, but you haven't provided a constructor that takes no arguments. Defining an object of type `foo` (or `No`) without an initializer requires a constructor that takes no arguments.

If I add something like:

```
foo() { }
```

inside the class definition, it compiles without error. Or I can change the object declaration from

```
foo obj;
```

to

```
foo obj(42);
```

which invokes the provided constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Each object should be initialized in array. You need default constructor for declaring array of objects in manner you do declare.

If default constructor does not have sense in your case you may initialize each object by yourself thus make somthing like this `No adj[101] { No(1), No(2), ..., No(101)};`

Answer (score 0):

As, previously said. No *adj[101] is an array of pointers.
But if you wanted to initalize using the constructor, do like this: Node adj(101).